# When to use a php function vs a drupal_ equivalent function?

Tags: 7, coding-standards

I come from update my [Coder](https://www.drupal.org/project/coder) module to the v1.3 and when I go to check one custom module I see the following message:

> Line 71: in most cases, replace the string function with the drupal_
>   equivalent string functions
>
> ```
> $node_type = substr($form_id, 0, -10);
> ```
>
> Line 187: in most cases, replace the string function with the drupal_ equivalent string functions
>
> ```
> $info->language = ($info->language == 'und' || empty($info->language)) ? t('Undetermined') : ucfirst($info->language);
> ```

So, why I need to use the [drupal_substr()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!unicode.inc/function/drupal_substr/7.x) and [drupal_ucfirst()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!unicode.inc/function/drupal_ucfirst/7.x) in this case? And in general why to use the drupal_ equivalent functions when we have the php functions?

Comment: @George see this https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!unicode.inc/function/drupal_ucfirst/7.x and this https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!unicode.inc/function/drupal_substr/7.x

Comment: I stand corrected! If they're used for Unicode purposes in Drupal core I can only assume that you'd need them if you had specific Unicode support requirements... the core documentation does say that you should normally use the PHP equivalent of substr first as it is faster...

Comment: It needs to be accounted for particularly if you are doing contrib work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most PHP string function don't handle unicode characters. For this you need to use their `mb_*` variants, which are (were?) not always available on some host. The `drupal_*` variants ensure unicode compatibility. They wrap `mb_*` functions and provide pure PHP implementations for when they are not available.

So, this recommendation is there to ensure portability of your code across hosts.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: It's a rule of thumb to use the Drupal API functions instead of PHP functions when available.

Comment: @NoSssweat Even if I don't use unicode?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I just noticed in [drupal_substr()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!unicode.inc/function/drupal_substr/7.x) it says `"the usage of PHP's normal strpos/substr is safe and much faster."` Hmmm this is probably the exception to the rule of thumb.

Comment: The complete sentence is "Note that for cutting off a string at a known character/substring location, the usage of PHP's normal strpos/substr is safe and much faster.", so that's a specific usage of the function where the original PHP function is considered safe.
You always use unicode when working with Drupal as it use only UTF-8.